# Issue making 3 columns from Calculations on a single column

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two tables that I am trying to join and display the count of transactions by year grouped by user_name. The data is from two separate tables: users and transactions. I need the output to have four total columns: user_name, 2019, 2020, 2021. The year of the transaction can be identified by the first two digits of the transaction_id: 19ABXY would be from 2019, 20TUZI would be from 2020, etc. Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT users.user_name
,    COUNT(case when transactions.transaction_id LIKE '19%'
,    COUNT(case when transactions.transaction_id LIKE '20%'
,    COUNT(case when transactions.transaction_id LIKE '21%'
FROM users
INNER JOIN transactions on users.user_id=transaction.user_id
GROUP BY users.user_name;
```

This returns a syntax error.

I have looked at other ways to create multiple columns from a single column that generally matches the required commands here, but have not found anything that doesn't return an error. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your use of `COUNT()` is missing the close-parens. You probably means something like: `SELECT users.user_name, SUM(case when transactions.transaction_id LIKE '19%' THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS '2019',
SUM(case when transactions.transaction_id LIKE '20%' THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS '2020',
SUM(case when transactions.transaction_id LIKE '21%' THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS '2021' ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT users.user_name
 ,    sum(case when transactions.transaction_id LIKE '19%' then 1 else 0 end)as tran_19
,    sum(case when transactions.transaction_id LIKE '20%' then 1 else 0 end)as tran_20
,    sum(case when transactions.transaction_id LIKE '21%' then 1 else 0 end)as tran_21
FROM users
INNER JOIN transactions on users.user_id=transaction.user_id
GROUP BY users.user_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You would at least need to finish your `CASE` expressions and close the parentheses for each column.

```
COUNT(case when transactions.transaction_id LIKE '19%' THEN 1 END)
                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

COUNT() works because the CASE returns NULL if there is no match, and COUNT() ignores NULLs.